# BlackBerry stream audio/STOP Stream

Tags: blackberry, stream

)

I'm newbie in programming and have problem.

My code:

```
  choiceFieldANTYFM = new ObjectChoiceField("Wybierz stację(6)", new String[]{"Warszawa [96kb]"});
  choiceFieldANTYFM.setChangeListener(this);
  btnSelectantyfm = new ButtonField("Słuchaj!", FIELD_HCENTER | ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
  btnSelectantyfm.setChangeListener(this);
  stopplaying = new ButtonField("STOP", FIELD_HCENTER | ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
  stopplaying.setChangeListener(this);

   add(choiceFieldANTYFM);
   add(btnSelectantyfm);
   add(stopplaying);
```

and other:

```
public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
 if (field == btnSelectantyfm)

  {
     System.out.println("Selected item: " + Integer.toString(choiceField.getSelectedIndex()));
  }if (field == btnSelect)
 {

     switch (choiceField.getSelectedIndex())
    {

case 0:

       try {
     String url = "http://94.23.220.75:6000;deviceside=false;ConnectionUID=GPMDSEU01";
      Player player;
      player = javax.microedition.media.Manager.createPlayer(url);
      player.start();
 } 
      catch (Exception e) {
      Dialog.alert(e.toString());
  }


        break;
```

Ok,When I push play it goes music in the application.

When push it again looped back. This is the second problem :)

I want to stop the stream when push stop button and even if it was possible to change the volume keys + and - :)

JDE 5.0 :)

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than do `btnSelectantyfm.setChangeListener(this);` which would imply that your Screen is implementing `FieldChangeListener` declare separate `FieldChangeListener` objects for each button as follows:

```
btnSelectantyfm.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener(){

    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context){
        //start playing code here
        player.start();
    }
});

stopplaying.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener(){

    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context){
        //stop playing code here
        player.stop();
    }
});
```

Now you need to declare the `Player` object as a member variable so that the play and pause FieldChangeListeners can access it. To stop the Player playing just do `player.stop()`.

For changing the volume when the volume keys are pressed you will need to:

1. Implement a `KeyListener` to perform actions when the side volume keys are pressed
2. Get the `VolumeControl` from the Player by doing `player.getControl("VolumeControl");`
3. Update the `VolumeControl` with the new desired volume

Comment: Thank you very much for uour response :) I have loop problem not stop when press "Stop button"  This is a beta OTA application: http://goo.gl/EnPXH